# copy files to/from hebrew folders

Tags: batch-file, hebrew

I have the following bat file:

```
echo on

copy "camera uploads\*.pdf" "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\תיקיה 2018"

pause
```

it fails due to "file system cannot find the path specified"

what do I miss?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware that `"camera uploads*.pdf"` means `.pdf` files whose names start `camera uploads`? Do these files exist? Or perhaps you meant `"camera uploads\*.pdf"` - all `.pdf` files in the directory `camera uploads` ?

Comment: Maybe is related to the hebrew special characters used. But for lots of users is hard to test

Comment: Since equally-looking characters in Command Prompt and Windows Explorer might not be the same due to poor Unicode support, you could try to use short names (check out the `/X` option of the [`dir` command](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html))...

Answer (score 0):

As @Magoo said:

> Are you aware that `"camera uploads*.pdf"` means .pdf files whose names start 
>   camera uploads? Do these files exist? Or perhaps you meant "camera `uploads\*.pdf`" 
>   - all .pdf files in the directory camera uploads

try making it `uploads\*.pdf`

if that doesn't work, try removing the Hebrew characters, as @JorgeHortelano (indirectly) said:

> Maybe is related to the Hebrew special characters used. But for lots of users is hard to test

Comment: I am not sure why you dont see the \
it exists in the original post...
anyway, when I changed the hebrew folder to english - it works finr (with a long english name) so I am sure its related to the hebrew...

Comment: i couldn't see it when i created this

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, apparently there was an invisible character instead of a normal space between Camera and Uploads. I simply deleted the weird space and replaced it with a normal space by renaming the file using Windows File Explorer.